# Deserializing simple xml returns empty values

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to read a simple xml and deserialize it through a class. But it returns empty value for all the parameters present in the xml.
Could anyone help me out with fixing the empty return value issue while deserialzing the following xml.

```
<Batch>
    <description>example</description>
    <fileField>DesktopA</fileField>
    <output>The</output>
    <input>home</input>
    <input>green</input>
    <parameters>
        <action>1</action>
        <item>2</item>          
    </parameters>
    <parameters>
        <action>1</action>
        <item>4</item>          
    </parametersField>
</Batch>
```

Class :

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class Batch {

    private string description;

    private string fileField;

    private string output;

    private string[] input;

    private Parameter[] parameters;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Description {
        get {
            return this.description;
        }
        set {
            this.description = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string File {
        get {
            return this.fileField;
        }
        set {
            this.fileField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Output {
        get {
            return this.output;
        }
        set {
            this.output = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElement]
    public string[] Input {
        get {
            return this.input;
        }
        set {
            this.input = value;
        }
    }

   /// <remarks/>
   [XmlElement]
   public Parameter[] Parameters {
        get {
            return this.parameters;
        }
        set {
            this.parameters = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>

public partial class Parameter {


    private sbyte action;  

    private object item;



    /// <remarks/>
    public sbyte Action {
        get {
            return this.action;
        }
        set {
            this.action = value;
        }
    }

   /// <remarks/>
   [XmlElement]
   public object Item {
        get {
            return this.item;
        }
        set {
            this.item = value;
        }
    }
```

The deserializaion method :

```
XmlSerializer reader;
                Type bt = batchInfo.GetType();

                reader = new XmlSerializer(bt);                 
                System.IO.StreamReader file =
                   new System.IO.StreamReader(testScriptFile, System.Text.Encoding.Default);                
            batchInfo = (Batch)reader.Deserialize(file);
```

Comment: Your properties like `description` need to have a public setter. If you want to have different property names then the ones in the xml you could use attributes.

Comment: Thanks. But I have no problem in using same name from the xml. And I am not aware regarding attributes since I am new to xml. can u help me with changing the code sample accoringly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following models to deserialize your xml. It makes use of the `XmlElement` attribute.

```
public class Parameter
{
    [XmlElement("action")]
    public int Action { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public int Item { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Batch")]
public class Batch
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("fileField")]
    public string FileField { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("output")]
    public string Output { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("input")]
    public List<string> Inputs { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("parameters")]
    public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

And by using this code you can execute the deserialization.

```
var xml = @"
    <Batch>
        <description>example</description>
        <fileField>DesktopA</fileField>
        <output>The</output>
        <input>home</input>
        <input>green</input>
        <parameters>
            <action>1</action>
            <item>2</item>          
        </parameters>
        <parameters>
            <action>1</action>
            <item>4</item>          
        </parameters>
    </Batch>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Batch));
var textReader = new StringReader(xml);
var obj = (Batch) serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
```

Or when reading from a file

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Batch));
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\mypath\myFile.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    var obj = (Batch)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Other fields are fine except for the list fields. Its still null.

Comment: @Sanga When I run it with the xml in my answer it works. Maybe the xml is different to the one you posted?

Comment: The Xml i use is the same but I have to input it as file rather than variable. I guess that may cause this issue. Is it possible to work with the xml as file input. if so, Can u pls change the deserialization part accordingly?

Comment: @Sanga Would be quite strange if some values are read while others aren't but I added the reading part anyway.

Comment: Hi. I am not sure why it works now but it does. Thanks a lot for your help. Marked as answer. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your XML properly, you can see that there is a problem on your parameter. You have , but it should be

```
<Batch>
    <description>example</description>
    <fileField>DesktopA</fileField>
    <output>The</output>
    <input>home</input>
    <input>green</input>
    <parameters>
        <action>1</action>
        <item>2</item>          
    </parameters>
    <parameters>
        <action>1</action>
        <item>4</item>          
    </parameters>
</Batch>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for noting that out. But fixing it doesn't help either. Changin the properties to public helped. But I need to restrict the access of variables other then deserializing. Any Idea on this?